# c# datasource is returning System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

i have a combobox cbAnalytes:

```
cbAnalytes.DataSource = ConnectandReadList(qcvalues_query);
```

where the ConnectandReadList is:

```
public DataTable ConnectandReadList(string query)
{
    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
    string connection_string = "Data Source=hermes;database=qcvalues; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        var command = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
    return ds;
}
```

for some reason it populates the combobox with:

```
System.Data.DataRowView
System.Data.DataRowView
System.Data.DataRowView
System.Data.DataRowView
System.Data.DataRowView
```

does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What are you setting your `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` attributes to?  You need to set those properties for your combobox in order for it to know what to display.

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.net:

```
cbAnalytes.DataValueField = "ColumnName";
cbAnalytes.DataTextField = "ColumnName";
```

For Windows Forms:

```
cbAnalytes.DisplayMember = "ColumnName";
cbAnalytes.ValueMember = "ColumnName"; // don't set this if you want the Value to be the DatRowView itself
```

Comment: i want it to display results of the query

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the Combobox' DisplayMember and ValueMember properties to the text and id columns?

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/scomlistcontrolbinding.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In brief, you need to bind the displayed item properties (DisplayMember and ValueMember, as @AJ mentioned) of the combobox to *properties of* your DataTable's rows (i.e. the columns you want to have the combobox use). Currently, it's blindly attempting to display the object being provided as the cbo's datasource. It does this by calling `object.ToString()`, which, unless overridden, tends to return the name of the type.

Answer (score 0):

your combo box should look similar to this

```
<cc1:ComboBox 
            ID="cbAnalytes" 
            DataTextField="DATAROWPROPERTYHERE" 
            DataValueField="DATAROWPROPERTYHERE" 
            runat="server" >
</cc1:ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may assign field names which are different from the result set returned by the data adapter/reader or the select statement. Pls, check the field names.